# How can I permit array in rails post request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

Hey I am trying permit these parameters in rails create controller . I am using a ajax post request to send an array as a params . But I am unable to access it in rails controller . How can I permit this and show it in json as a response .

```
 Parameters: {"combination_dose"=>{"shared_items"=>{"0"=>{"entity_id"=>"253", "position"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"entity_id"=>"823", "position"=>"2"}}}}
```

Comment: Does this work `params.require(:combination_dose).permit(shared_items: [:entity_id, :position])`?

Comment: ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'shared_items' for CombinationDose.): not working

Comment: Does your `combination_dose` table has `shared_items` column?

Comment: no I am creating an array using ajax post request shared_items is an array

Comment: This is maybe a good introduction for Nested parameters ` http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html`

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to access it by doing:
`params.require(:combination_dose).permit(shared_items: [:entity_id, :position])`